# Are overlays on top of full-screen flash video possible?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, fullscreen

Is there a generic way, preferably in Javascript but flash would be okay, I guess, to put an overlay on top of full-screen flash video without editing the video player?

The particular use case is that I'd like to add growl-like notifications to some live streaming stuff without writing a lot of AS that ties me to a specific player. It seems that most of the players would not allow this anyway.

Even finding out that this is definitively impossible would be okay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: no

Only way around this would be to load what you want to appear over the top of the full-screen video into the SWF itself.

Comment: Nuts. Thanks. Appreciate the response.