# How can i place an HTML overlay on top of a full screen flash video?

Tags: html, flash

I have a flash video that is playing in full screen and I want to be able to put an HTML overlay on top of it (with images, links, background, etc.).

I kind of want to do something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1tjQ.jpg

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: Do you mean this? [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/BMkTM/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are overlays on top of full-screen flash video possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643473/are-overlays-on-top-of-full-screen-flash-video-possible)

Comment: Are you developing a desktop app or website for use in a browser? If it's a desktop app you can render HTML inside Flash when it's running as Air, if not then as everyone else states - you can't do this for web.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to put image overlay in full screen. http://bit.ly/UuD21S

You can do text though.

Comment: How would I get text to show on top of a full screen flash? "HTML text" I mean, so nothing in flash itself

Comment: @user1306636 [Check out this](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?232216-HTML-Text-over-SWF-Background). Seems like the suggest way worked. Let me know. I could try to put something together.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put HTML div over **third party** flash element, because full screen flash is **not** swf container stretched to the full screen, but completely new window. If you got multi monitor setup and switch to full screen flash movie, then i.e. on Windows you will new window on you taskbar with Flash icon. So the only way to have something over Flash player is to change the flash player.

Comment: It's our own flash though that we are using, but since it's not a third party element, what can we do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this when the flash player is full screen out side of the browser:
check this link out
 " http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470521/So-You-Want-A-FullScreen-Browser-Huh.htm#click"

this would be the  closest way  to go, but it still will be in a window:
So use CSS with HTML to set the flash SWF to the background: try using z-indexValue in CSS when placing your flash div

let us know how you go