# Sending notifications and/or messages to a Flash/Silverlight/HTML5 player in fullscreen

Tags: silverlight, actionscript, html5-video, flash

I'm researching for a project that would need to send messages and/or have interaction with a user while watching a video full-screen on a website. My understanding was that once Flash (or any of the other programs) start, the browser has no control over the process. I can find little to no information on the possibilities. Would this be possible without having an user install separate software?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Aah.. I think you're confusing how html5 video fullscreen works with Flash Player's way. The browsers choose to fullscreen the video object **only**. In Flash player the **entire** Flash content can be fullscreen. So you just put video on one layer and your text interactions in another layer (above) and it all goes fulscreen at once (together). Do I make sense? just ask... **[See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558443/full-screen-interactive-mode-the-allow-button-click-is-passed-to-the-applicat)** if it helps also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly didn't do my homework, have found that this will be nearly impossible:

[Are overlays on top of full-screen flash video possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643473/are-overlays-on-top-of-full-screen-flash-video-possible)

Comment: Depends what you're doing. If you code a flash app that receives messages into a textbox inside the application (SWF) then it will work in fullscreen (i.e instant messaging/chat). That link is talking about notifications like from an external app. For instance having a "one new email" or "new update available" notification from desktop app showing over current full screen video as needed. That one wont happen..

Answer (score 0):

I think for flash (**flash player 11.3 and higher**) and HTML5 it is possible, for silverlight I don't know.

For flash, for interaction in fullscreen mode, you should use `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` instead of `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`, take a look here for more details about that : [Adobe.com : Working with full-screen mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB) and then add what you need of interaction.

For HTML5, you can do like youtube player for exemple so you create you own video player and when you want to pass to fullscreen mode, you do a fullscreen of your video player and not the `<video>` element and then you can do all what you need as in a normal html page in the normal mode.

Comment: But in fullscreen html5 video, can he also have a html5 (JScript?) messaging or chat application placed on top of the video too? That is his question. He hasn't started but needs options on possibilities

Comment: Yes of course he can because when we do a fullscreen of the html5 video element (`<video>`) then we can't touch anything in the page because the video element will take the whole screen and focus, but when we create a video player based of course on html5 video element with other elements (controls panel, chat zone, share buttons, ...) when we do a fullscreen of it (our video player) and not the html5 video element, we have just to work in resizing elements as in a normal html content just it's in "zoom" mode.

Comment: Why some people down-vote and don't explain (or give better solution) I don't know..!! Anyway your idea sounds plausible. All he can do now is try either HTML5 or Flash and see how it goes.

Comment: @VC.One Don't care man about people who have the passion to down-vote answers of others without even bothering to justify their decision.